# Parsing csv and printing data in batch script

Tags: csv, batch-file, windows-server-2012-r2

I have this in my `trim_csv.bat` (I intend to trim trailing spaces of every entry in the csv).

`FOR /F "delims=;" %i IN (csv_exports\account.csv) DO @echo %i`
*(I have also tried enclosing the path with quotes, no difference.)*

**Executing it through cmd** results to:

`i was unexpected at this time.`

What do I misunderstand? I tried following syntax coming from `HELP FOR` but I feel like that is something simple that I just can't see.

PS: It's quite new in batch scripting as you can imagine.

Comment: Literally the eighth line of the help file for the `FOR` command: **To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead
of %variable.  Variable names are case sensitive, so %i is different
from %I.**

Comment: Regardless of the obvious issue, highlighted by @Squashman above, how does that trim trailing spaces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the code is going to be a part of a `bat` file, percents should be escaped as `%i` -> `%%i`:

```
FOR /F "delims=;" %%i IN (csv_exports\account.csv) DO @echo %%i
```